# Tab separated values in awk

Tags: awk

How do I select the first column from the TAB separated string?

```
# echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk -F'\t' '{print $1}'
```

The above will return the entire line and not just "LOAD_SETTLED" as expected.

Update:

I need to change the third column in the tab separated values.
The following does not work.

```
echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { -v var="$mycol_new" FS = "[ \t]+" } ; { print $1 $2 var $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 }' >> /pdump/temp.txt
```

This however works as expected if the separator is comma instead of tab.

```
echo $line | awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F'\t' '{print $1 "," $2 "," var "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9 "}' >> /pdump/temp.txt
```

Comment: awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ \t]+" } ; { print $1 }' # this is what I was looking for. Is my google search correct? :)

Comment: Thanks to this comment, I have discovered: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1,FS,$2,FS,$3}' myFile.txt` to print tab-delimited values of the first three columns.

Comment: Or perhaps simply `awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}; {print $1,$2,$3}' `

Comment: Both GNU and BSD awk support `-v` for setting variables. It's ugly to use `BEGIN {FS="\t"}` inside an *inline program*, and any open source contribution you try to make like that is likely to be objected to. Only do that if you are writing a *program file*. Also, it is discouraged to use `-F` instead of `-v FS=` because the latter makes clear that only `FS` is being set and not `OFS`. Confusion about that last point is what caused this post in the first place. That's why "good style" is important.

Comment: Please, no one, ever, should do what @Wok demonstrated. You don't enumerate [Input] Field Separators in your Output. You specify an Output Field Separator via the `OFS` variable.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky But to the unitiated like me, the fact that "FS" is supposed to mean "IFS" is not obvious. If I could write `-v IFS="\t"` that would be better.  And I should probably be scripting in Python instead of awk. But here I am.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You need to set the `OFS` variable (output field separator) to be a tab:

```
echo "$line" | 
awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'
```

(make sure you quote the `$line` variable in the echo statement)

Comment: What is the purpose of the $ in $'\t'?

Comment: Answering my own question from the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html): The $' ... ' quoted string-expansion construct is a mechanism that uses escaped octal or hex values ..., e.g., quote=$'\042'.

Comment: @AmrMostafa, too bad that guide has a misleading explanation leading one to think that you don't the `$` in `$'\t'` is not needed. [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is better: "Of these, `$'...'` is the most common, and acts just like single quotes except that backslash-escaped combinations are expanded as specified by the ANSI C standard".

Comment: In hindsight, the `$'\t'` is not necessary. awk understands the string `"\t"` to be a tab character

Comment: `echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk  '{print $1}'` should this not be sufficient?

Comment: Open Source Contributors, I beg you, please don't submit stuff like `awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} …'`. That should be `awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '…'`. It may seem pedantic, but being inconsistent increases the chances that a later contributor will introduce a bug because they misunderstand your code.

Comment: This answer could use improvement. Lots of bash specific stuff going on, almost no explanation. It's not easy to distinguish what's the answer and what's unrelated

Comment: So, is `-v OFS='\t'` always preferred over `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}`?

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```sh
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' ...
```

---

**Example from [one of my scripts](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/abe1652c2d5c78c35b92ad02bdf0d0af#file-dns_update-sh-L36-L39).**

I use the `FS` and `OFS` variables to manipulate BIND zone files, which are tab delimited:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' \
    -v record_type=$record_type \
    -v hostname=$hostname \
    -v ip_address=$ip_address '
$1==hostname && $3==record_type {$4=ip_address}
{print}
' $zone_file > $temp
```

This is a clean and easy to read way to do this.

Answer (score 23):

Make sure they're really tabs! In bash, you can insert a tab using <kbd>C-v TAB</kbd>

```
$ echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $1}'
LOAD_SETTLED
```

Answer (score 20):

You can set the Field Separator:

```
... | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1}'
```

Excellent read:

https://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Field_Separators.html

Comment: The most easy way to achieve this. By the way the most clearly to me...

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk -v var="test" 'BEGIN { FS = "[ \t]+" } ; { print $1 "\t" var "\t" $3 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fields are separated by tabs - this works for me in Linux.

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1}' < tab_delimited_file.txt
```

I use this to process data generated by `mysql`, which generates tab-separated output in batch mode.

From awk man page:

```
   -F fs
   --field-separator fs
          Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS prede‐
          fined variable).
```

Answer (score 0):

- 1st column only

  — `awk NF=1 FS='\t'`

> ```
>  LOAD_SETTLED
> ```

- First 3 columns

  — `awk NF=3 FS='\t' OFS='\t'`

> ```
>  LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT    2011-01-13
> ```

- Except first 2 columns

  — `{g,n}awk NF=NF OFS= FS='^([^\t]+\t){2}'`

  —   `{m}awk NF=NF OFS= FS='^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t'`

> ```
>  2011-01-13    03:50:01
> ```

- Last column only

  — `awk '($!NF=$NF)^_' FS='\t'`, or

  — `awk NF=NF OFS= FS='^.*\t'`

> ```
>  03:50:01
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Should this not work?

```
echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk '{print $1}'
```