# how to parse tsv file with AWK

Tags: csv, awk

I  need to parse, iterate through an .tsv file, using awk.

The file path is correct, tested in terminal.
getting error "***cat: ./datalist.tsv No such file or directory***"

the tsv file have few rows, tab separated. plan is to loop through the tsv file content.

here is my code, for **filename.awk** :

Comment: please add sample input and corresponding expected output for that.. and try to explain on what basis conversion is done..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab separated values in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374239/tab-separated-values-in-awk)

Comment: *"cat: ./datalist.tsv No such file or directory"* looks very much like the path actually **isn't** correct.

Comment: sorry, but later found that  the file path was wrong. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `cat` to read a TSV file. Instead, just read the file directly.

For example:

```
#!/bin/gawk
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
    OFS = ","
    ORS = "\r\n"
    while (( getline < "datalist.tsv" ) > 0) {
        print $1,$2,$3
    }
}
```

Example input (all spaces between the fields are just a single tab):

```
1   2   3
ab  bc  cd
abc bcd cde
```

Example output:

```
1,2,3
ab,bc,cd
abc,bcd,cde
```

NOTE: if the fields inside your TSV file never have spaces in them, like in my example input, you don't even need to change field separator `FS="\t"` as the fields will be split on spaces as well as tabs by default.

Comment: Reading the file in the `BEGIN` block is still just ... weird.  `awk -F _` is all you need here.

Answer (score 1):

You are enormously overcomplicating things.  Why are you doing the reading in the `BEGIN` block and why do you set `OFS` to something else than the output separator you apparently actually want?

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="_"; ORS="\"\r\n" } { print $1, $2, $3 }' ./datalist.tsv
```

If the file is *properly* TSV there are a few quirks you may need to work around. The format allows for a field to contain the delimiter if it is inside double quotes; apparently, the file you are reading *does* have double quotes (why else do you put `"` in the `ORS`?) so a complete solution would parse the quotes and ignore the field separator if it's inside a pair of (unescaped!) quotes. (See e.g. [this question.)](/q/7804673)

Comment: I don't think proper TSV allows the delimiter inside a field. At least, not in IANA standard: "Note that fields that contain tabs are not allowable in this encoding." http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values