# How to parse very big files in python?

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a very big tsv file: 1.5 GB. i want to parse this file. Im using the following function:

```
def readEvalFileAsDictInverse(evalFile):
  eval = open(evalFile, "r")
  evalIDs = {}
  for row in eval:
    ids = row.split("\t")
    if ids[0] not in evalIDs.keys():
      evalIDs[ids[0]] = []
    evalIDs[ids[0]].append(ids[1])
  eval.close()


  return evalIDs
```

It is take more than 10 hours and it is still working. I dont know  how to accelerate this step and if there is another method to parse such as file

Comment: Maybe duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: im working on a linux server with 130 gb as ram.

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot nope, not at all. OP isn't reading the lines first.

Comment: @bib Stepping back a little, what do you plan to use dictionary `eval` for?

Comment: which python version are you using BTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you can make it somewhat faster; change it:

```
if ids[0] not in evalIDs.keys():
      evalIDs[ids[0]] = []
evalIDs[ids[0]].append(ids[1])
```

to

```
evalIDs.setdefault(ids[0],[]).append(ids[1])
```

The 1st solution searches 3 times in the "evalID" dictionary.

Comment: `setdefault` is slower than a defaultdict. `timeit.timeit(lambda : d.setdefault('x',[]).append(1))` reports `0.4583683079981711` and `timeit.timeit(lambda : c['x'].append(1))` reports `0.28720847200020216` where `d` is `{}` and `c` is `collections.defaultdict(list)`. All the answers have recommended so. Why have you selected this as the correct one? The solution here is inferior to the others mentioned.

Comment: I can't measure significant difference (Python 3.7.1), but the OP should measure it.

Comment: The defaultdict is roughly twice as fast as the setdefault in my measurement. (3.5.3) and I think that's reasonable given how setdefault evaluates its arguments each time you call it (a new empty list is created each time).

Answer (score 3):

several issues here:

- testing for keys with `if ids[0] not in evalIDs.keys()` takes *forever* in python 2, because `keys()` is a `list`. `.keys()` is rarely useful anyway. A better way already is `if ids[0] not in evalIDs`, but, but...
- why not use a `collections.defaultdict` instead?
- why not use `csv` module?
- overriding `eval` built-in (well, not really an issue seeing how dangerous it is)

my proposal:

```
import csv, collections

def readEvalFileAsDictInverse(evalFile):
  with open(evalFile, "r") as handle:
     evalIDs = collections.defaultdict(list)
     cr = csv.reader(handle,delimiter='\t')
     for ids in cr:
        evalIDs[ids[0]].append(ids[1]]
```

the magic `evalIDs[ids[0]].append(ids[1]]` creates a `list` if doesn't already exist. It's also portable and very fast whatever the python version and saves a `if`

I don't think it could be faster with default libraries, but a pandas solution probably would.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

Use a `defaultdict(list)` instead of creating inner lists yourself *or* using `dict.setdefault()`.

`dict.setfdefault()` will create the defautvalue every time, thats a time burner - `defautldict(list)` does not - it is optimized:

```
from collections import defaultdict    
def readEvalFileAsDictInverse(evalFile):
  eval = open(evalFile, "r")
  evalIDs = defaultdict(list)
  for row in eval:
    ids = row.split("\t")
    evalIDs[ids[0]].append(ids[1])
  eval.close()
```

---

If your keys are valid file names you might want to investigate `awk` for much more performance then doing this in python.

Something along the lines of

```
awk -F $'\t' '{print > $1}' file1
```

will create your split files much faster and you can simply use the latter part of the following code to read from each file (assuming your keys are valid filenames) to construct your lists. (Attributation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376527/7505395) ) - You would need to grab your created files with `os.walk` or similar means. Each line inside the files will still be tab-seperated and contain the ID in front

---

If your keys are not filenames in their own right, consider storing your different lines into different files and only keep a dictionary of `key,filename` around.

After splitting the data, load the files as lists again:

Create testfile:

```
with open ("file.txt","w") as w:

    w.write("""
1\ttata\ti
2\tyipp\ti
3\turks\ti
1\tTTtata\ti
2\tYYyipp\ti
3\tUUurks\ti
1\ttttttttata\ti
2\tyyyyyyyipp\ti
3\tuuuuuuurks\ti

    """)
```

Code:

```
# f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename
def make_filename(k):
    """In case your keys contain non-filename-characters, make it a valid name"""          
    return k # assuming k is a valid file name else modify it

evalFile = "file.txt"
files = {}
with open(evalFile, "r") as eval_file:
    for line in eval_file:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        key,value, *rest = line.split("\t") # omit ,*rest if you only have 2 values
        fn = files.setdefault(key, make_filename(key))

        # this wil open and close files _a lot_ you might want to keep file handles
        # instead in your dict - but that depends on the key/data/lines ratio in 
        # your data - if you have few keys, file handles ought to be better, if 
        # have many it does not matter
        with open(fn,"a") as f:
            f.write(value+"\n")

# create your list data from your files:
data = {}
for key,fn in files.items():
    with open(fn) as r:
        data[key] = [x.strip() for x in r]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
# for my data: loaded from files called '1', '2' and '3'
{'1': ['tata', 'TTtata', 'tttttttata'], 
 '2': ['yipp', 'YYyipp', 'yyyyyyyipp'], 
 '3': ['urks', 'UUurks', 'uuuuuuurks']}
```

Comment: why creating a `defaultdict` and test the keys?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre copy & paste error - thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `evalIDs` to a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. You can avoid the `if` to check if a key is there.
2. Consider splitting the file externally using `split(1)` or even inside python using a read offset. Then use `multiprocessing.pool` to parallelise the loading.

Comment: can you please give more details. i dont have any idea about multiprocessing.pool

Comment: parallelize the loading won't do no good if I/O is the bottleneck

Comment: If I/O is the bottleneck, then yes, it won't do much good but apart from the `defaultdict` which everyone has suggested, it's the only other thing I can think of worth trying.

Comment: @bib Are all the lines in the file of the same length?